# Create unencrypted environment variables for Travis builds of Private Repos without defining them in .travis

Tags: environment-variables, travis-ci

I have a private GitHub Repo and I have autorised particular users to be able to create their own private forks of this repo.

I have Travis configured to generate code coverage which is sent to coveralls.io, where the API key is stored in an environment variable that is encrypted.

Travis encrypts environment variables and does not make them available to forks. This means PRs for my repo do not get code coverage reports before they are merged.

I understand that Travis does not make encrypted environment variables available to forks because this would expose the variable where the repo is public and anyone could generate a build.

In my case, my repo is private and I trust the users I have allowed to fork it.  So it would be fine for these variables to not be encrypted.

But I do not want to put the variables in `.travis.yml` because whilst I trust who has forked the repo, there are other parties who are not permitted to fork the repo who can still see the code (i.e. where copies of the code are kept on servers, or in backups.)

**Is there a strategy to set an evironment variable that is not encrypted and not defined in `.travis.yml`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a strategy to set an evironment variable that is not encrypted and not defined in .travis.yml?

When defining the variable in Travis.ci, enable the switch for **Display Value in Build Log**.

This will have the effect of not encrypting the variable, and the variable will be available for Pull Request builds.

This is appropriate where all the users who can raise a PR for your repo are trusted to know the Coveralls API key.